# Facebook More Button on the Wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I would like to create a more button similar to facebook that loads more items on the wall.
Could someone please advice on how I could get this working in PHP. Could you please point me to a resource or let me know a way how I can acheive this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you seek is called an `infinite scroller`.
Check out [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/) on how to create an infinite scrolling gallery on PHP. This one doesn't have the "more" button, it loads more content automatically every time you scroll the page down to the bottom. But it's easy enough to adapt it to work with a "more" button.

Edit: here's [another tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/), this time with the button.